# What are the best practices for user uploads with S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was wondering what you recommend for running a user upload system with s3.  I plan on using MongoDB for storing metadata such as the uploader, size, etc.  How should I go about storing the actual file in s3.

Here are some of my ideas, what do you think is the best?  All of these examples would involve saving the metadata to MongoDB.

1.Should I just store all the files in a bucket?
2. Maybe organize them into dates (e.g. 6/8/2014/mypicture.png)?
3.Should I save them all in one bucket, but with an added string (such as d1JdaZ9-mypicture.png) to avoid duplicates.
4. Or should I generate a long string for a folder, and store the file in that folder.  (to retain the original file name).  e.g. sh8sb36zkj391k4dhqk4n5e4ndsqule6/mypicture.png

Answer (score 6):

This depends primarily on how you intend to use the pictures and which objects/classes/modules/etc. in your code will actually deal with retrieving them.

1. If you find yourself wanting to do things like - "all user uploads on a particular day" - A simple naming convention with folders for the year, month and day along with a folder at the top level for the user's unique ID will solve the problem.
2. If you want to ensure uniqueness and avoid collisions in your bucket, you could generate a unique string too.

However, since you've got MongoDB which (i'm assuming) will actually handle these queries for user uploads by date, etc., it makes the choice of your bucket more aesthetic than functional.

If all you're storing in mongoDB is the key/URL, it doesn't really matter what the actual structure of your bucket is. Nevertheless, it makes sense to still split this up in some coherent way - maybe group all a user's uploads and give each a unique name (either generate a unique name or prefix a unique prefix to the file name).

That being said, do you think there might be a point when you might look at changing how your images are stored? You might move to a CDN. A third party might come up with an even cheaper/better product which you might want to try. In a case like that, simply storing the keys/URLs in your MongoDB is not a good idea since you'll have to update every entry.

To make this relatively future-proof, I suggest you give your uploads a definite structure. I usually opt for:

```
bucket_name/user_id/yyyy/mm/dd/unique_name.jpg
```

Your database then only needs to store the file name and the upload time stamp.

You can introduce a middle layer in your logic (a new class perhaps or just a helper function/method) which then generates the URL for a file based on this info. That way, if you change your storage method later, you only need to make a small change in this middle layer (after migrating your files of course) and not worry about MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response! I have a similar use case, but I'm also trying to make sure that when users delete uploads, they get deleted from S3. I posted a question on SO after trying to no avail to find a solution on my own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035485/how-to-store-and-reference-user-uploads-in-aws-s3-using-mongodb If you have thoughts on keeping the database and the object store in sync, I'd much appreciate it!